# squid proxy on redhat 7 is not allowing http traffic

Tags: linux, rhel, proxy, squid, http-proxy

I have two squid proxy servers. They both have same squid.conf file. One is allowing http traffic but other is not allowing http traffic.
https traffic is working via both squid proxies
squid config is below

```
    acl localnet src 172.22.0.0/16  # RFC1918 possible internal network
    acl SSL_ports port 443
    acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
    acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
    acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
    acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
    acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
    acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
    acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
    acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
    acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
    acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
    acl CONNECT method CONNECT
    acl allowedlist dstdomain "/etc/squid/allowedlist"
    http_access allow CONNECT localnet allowedlist
    http_access deny !Safe_ports
    http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
    http_access allow localnet manager
    http_access deny manager
    http_access allow localnet
    http_access deny all
    http_port 4128
    coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

I get this on site2 server

```
--2022-09-16 09:55:09--  http://google.com/
Connecting to squidproxysite2:4128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response..
```

.

on site1 its working

```
wget www.google.com
--2022-09-16 09:56:43--  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to squidproxysite1:4128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                              ] 15,368      --.-K/s   in 0.01s

2022-09-16 09:56:43 (1.20 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [15368]
```

Can anyone please advise what could be the issue?

Regards

Comment: on site 2 the request is to google.com and on site 1 it is www.google.com.   There may be a difference in your /etc/squid/allowedlist  for the different url

Comment: on site2 i tried with www and without www it does not work